# How do I make all content on screen go dark except the sidenav one you click on the burger button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the screen go dark when clicking and opening the sidenav and possibly freezing the rest of the screen so you cant scroll down the page but only on the sidenav, MY js for opening the nav is below currently I just have the background get darker but all the links on the page are still lit up and are clickable, How would I make everything go darker thank you

```
 // burger menu button with effects //
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "280px";
      document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,.8)";
      document.getElementById("despair").style.opacity = "0.33";
      document.getElementById("closebtn").style.marginLeft = "200px";
    }
```

Comment: Most of the time I see (and I use) a new `<div>` thrown up _in front of_ the body (higher z-index) with the opacity you want, which will block mouse clicks from reaching the body (thus "disabling" the links etc)

Comment: I agree with the comment above, and would like to add that you’ll make life easier for yourself if you utilize adding/removing classes from elements to update CSS, rather than writing inline stuff through JavaScript. You can use the `classList` function, in vanilla JS, to do that: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: Also, if you’re already trying to do this and it’s just not working, please post your relevant HTML/CSS, as well, so we can see what’s happening. It may just be you need to raise your z-index for your covering div.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan about classes & classList — I have a div with id="modal-cover" ... I just add the class `blocking` to it, and remove the class when done. Then it's just CSS to set the blocking and non-blocking styles, like `div#modal-cover { display:none; height:0; width:0; etc }` vs. `div#modal-cover.blocking { display:block; height:100%; width:100%; etc }` — I don't have to have a bunch of code setting and resetting a lot of style attributes. One simple line `cover.classList.toggle('blocking')` adds/removes the class.

Answer (score 1):

This basic example will put a blocking cover in front of the page when the button is clicked. As I said in a comment, it functions by using the element [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and toggling a class on the div that acts as a cover.

In this sample the cover is removed after 5 seconds; in reality you would remove the cover after some event, such as when the user made another choice in your sidenav, or, if navigation from the sidenav went to another page you wouldn't have to remove the cover because the new destination page would not put it up initially.

For more precise control you can use [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) in place of [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

If you wanted to have your sidenav remain available (not be blocked) you could set it at a higher z-index than the cover.

```js
const cover = document.getElementById('cover');
const blockit = document.getElementById('blockit');

blockit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    cover.classList.toggle('covering');
    window.setTimeout(function() { cover.classList.toggle('covering'); }, 5000);
});
```

```css
/*
 The cover starts off not being displayed,
 with a size of 0 x 0 pixels, and "behind"
 the rest of the page (negative z-index)
*/
div#cover {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
/*
 When the "covering" class is added to the cover
 it is displayed, has the size set to 100%, and
 is raised to z-index 100, in front of the rest
 of the page content.
*/
div#cover.covering {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 30%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
  This is a sample paragraph. It has a link to
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>
  within the text of the paragraph. You want to make that link unclickable.
  </p>
  <button id="blockit">Block It</button>
</main>
<div id="cover"></div>
```